# how to target the first div with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I am new to jquery, so please bear with me. I need to find a way to always get the first `div` from every series of divs with the same class that appears on a page so that I can add them some specific css styling to it. So technically I need something similar to `:first-child` in css.

I tried using `.first()` but that only got me the first `div` from the first series of 'divs' with that class name.

Example:

```
<div class="expl">....</div> <!-- need to target this div-->
<div class="expl">....</div>
<div class="expl">....</div>

<h1>....</h1> - this is just an example, we can have any other html tag/content here
<div class="expl">....</div> <!-- and this div-->
<div class="expl">....</div>
<div class="expl">....</div>

<p>....</p>
<div class="expl">....</div> <!-- and this div-->
<div class="expl">....</div>
<div class="expl">....</div>
```

Comment: According to your example you need to target 1-st, 4-th and 7-th divs.

Comment: Try this `$('div.expl').eq(3n)` , it will  target 1-st, 4-th and 7-th divs.

Comment: that's just a random example. I could have different number of divs and between them any other content. I need something more dynamic for any case scenario.

Comment: Try these `$('div.expl').first()` and `$('h1,p').next('div.expl')` or `$('div.expl').first()` and `$('h1 + div.expl,p + div.expl')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this CSS selector:

```
*:not(.expl) + .expl
```

This will target any `.expl` element immediately following a non `.expl` element. Obviously you can use jQuery for that, or not, depending on your requirements.

<kbd>[**Working example**](http://jsbin.com/kuhuruwa/1/edit)</kbd>

Comment: Perfect. It's just what I needed. I didn't knew about the *:not property. Right before you added the answer, I was considering adding each html tag + .expl which still wouldn't have been good enough because it didn't cover the situations in which I had a div before my div with .expl.

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap your div sets in another div like this:

```
<div class="exp-wrapper">
  <div class="expl">....</div> <!-- need to target this div-->
  <div class="expl">....</div>
  <div class="expl">....</div>
</div>
<h1>....</h1>
<div class="exp-wrapper">
   <div class="expl">....</div> <!-- and this div-->
   <div class="expl">....</div>
   <div class="expl">....</div>
</div>

<p>....</p>
<div class="exp-wrapper">
   <div class="expl">....</div> <!-- and this div-->
   <div class="expl">....</div>
   <div class="expl">....</div>
</div>
```

Then it would be easy to select first div inside wrapper.

```
$(".exp-wrapper div:first")
```

UPDATE: 
Maybe something like this:

```
$(".expl:first").add($(":not(.expl)").next(".expl"));
```

Comment: I can't do that, the divs are generated by a plugin and I have to keep it simple and not add anything else to it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Sunyatasattva's CSS answer, the jQuery equivalent is the following (using the [Next Adjacent Selector](https://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-Selector/) of JQuery):

```
var theThingsIWant = $(".expl:first").add(":not(.expl) + .expl");
```

A working example can be seen on this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cQH58/)

To break it down:

- `$(".expl:first")` - find the very first div
- `.add(":not(.expl) + .expl")` - also include any element with the `expl` class which is immediately preceded by a sibling which is *not* an element with `expl` class.

See https://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-Selector/ for a bit more detail.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. This also works great, but I went with the css in the end, it's more up my alley.

Comment: Sure, no problem :) If it's for styling then absolutely CSS is the way. If you needed to do some code manipulation with them, then at least there's a way with javascript too.

Answer (score 0):

```
var divs = [$("div.expl").first(),
$("h1").first().next("div.expl").first(),
$("p").first().next("div.expl").first()];
```

This is a much more robust solution though.

```
var selectAfter = function(what,whichIsAfter) {
    return $(what).filter(function() {
        return $(this).prev().not(what).is(whichIsAfter);
    });
}
var divs = selectAfter("div.expl","*").add("div.expl:first");
```

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/5gTcC/1/